# Why do so many people trade a bankrupt company's stock?

Tags: stocks, bankruptcy

I noticed that `GTAT` still has a lot of trading volumes after its announcement of bankruptcy. Why people still buy it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may have some value!  Investopedia has a [well-written quick article](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/bankruptpublicfirm.asp) on how stock holders may still get some portion of the liquidated assets.  While there is generally little left for common shareholders if the price of those shares is tiny and some money does come back to shareholders there can still be significant profit to be made.

As to why the trading volume is so high... there are many firms and hedge funds that specialize in calculating the value of and buying distressed debt and stock.  They often compete with each other to by the stock/debt that common shareholders are trying to get rid of.  In this particular case, there is a lot of popular interest, intellectual property at stake and [pending lawsuits](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/193912-court-filings-allege-apple-mismanagement-drove-sapphire-company-into-ground) that probably boosts volume.